# Integrate standalone CURL into PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have XAMPP 1.7.4 installed in my local environment. With this version, my PHP only had cURL library with SSL Version 0.9.8o, TLS 1.0

I need to use cURL for my app, but unfortunately, the API server require TLS 1.1 or greater.

So I have to upgrade my cURL version, but I can't upgrade my whole XAMPP. Because current app already Live with this XAMPP version. Therefore, I want to install new standalone cURL and integrate that cURL with my PHP.

I already success install my standalone cURL and use it in CMD.

But I still failed to use cURL programmatically in PHP.

My question is, how can I integrate standalone cURL with PHP?

Things I already try to do :

1. commented `php_curl.dll` in `php.ini`
2. add `curl.exe` folder to PATH variable
3. add PHP folder to PATH variable
4. Research another sites

Comment: Upgrading your XAMPP server shouldn't be a problem. Unless the application you build requires certain functions that are no longer available in PHP 5.6 or 7, Just make sure to backup the databases before attempting to upgrade. And if you really must use your current request use exec()

Comment: that's what I'm afraid of. I have to make sure that everything will be alright with new environment. considering my App is big enough, that will be a really big task. I hope I only have to upgrade my cURL. Is it can be done?

Comment: Unfortunately you cant  just replace the curl lib of PHP as it has been compiled with a certain version of PHP.

Comment: You could try recompiling PHP with an upgraded version of curl, but to be honest the testing you'd need to do might be the equivalent to just upgrading PHP. Alternatively you could move your API code to another server with the right version of PHP on it, and then remote control it with your own HTTP API that does not need TLS 1.1.

Comment: _“Because current app already Live with this XAMPP version”_ – XAMPP is not meant to run production websites in the first place ...

Comment: @halfer : yeah thanks for editing my post man. so, you mean I create the second environment that will have the right version of PHP, and I will access the API with this environment, right? But how can I integrate these apps? how my first apps get the return of API that the second Apps had?

Comment: @CBroe : ahh sorry.. no, there is no XAMPP in my Live Environment. There's only standalone PHP, Apache, MySQL with same version that XAMPP 1.7.4 have

Comment: So, you have two web servers: your main one (TLS 1.0) stays the same, and a new one (TLS 1.1). Move your API calling code to the new one, and then write some code there that exposes this over TLS 1.0. Effectively you'd be sending an API call from old server to new server to external API server.

Comment: well, that is a good idea. I will try that. thanks so much man!